# Anaconda won't update spyder

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I had Spyder 3.1.3 installed an running fine. 
Then I heard about "anaconda navigator" - which I never had launched it before - so I launched it, took a look around, installed glueviz and quit.

Next time I opened spyder - not from the navigator, from the shortcut I've always used (with this command: `C:\Anaconda2\pythonw.exe C:\Anaconda2\cwp.py C:\Anaconda2 "C:/Anaconda2/pythonw.exe" "C:/Anaconda2/Scripts/spyder-script.py" --new-instance`), it launched spyder version 2.3.8.

Then I went to the command line and tried to update spyder with the `conda update spyder`command and I get this:

```
C:\>conda update spyder
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda2:
#
spyder                    2.3.8                    py27_1

C:\>
```

nothing happens.
If I try to update it from the navigator (running as admin), I get an error saying  "spyder cannot be installed on this environment"

Any ideas what can I do to properly update spyder?

EDIT:
I updated pandas and skpyder downgraded to version 2.2.0...

Thanks

Comment: Try starting it with admin privileges

Comment: everything I did was with admin privileges

Comment: Based on the steps you took, it seems that one or more of the packages you installed conflicts with the most recent version of Spyder. You'll have to uninstall those to install the most recent version.

Comment: Please try `conda remove spyder-app` and try to update Spyder again. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

With admin privilege type (if one does not uninstall before installing it gets 'stuck' for hours)

**conda uninstall spyder**

**conda install spyder=5.1.5**